# Getting "subscript out of range" error from "Find" result

Tags: excel, vbscript

I would like to find a string in an Excel worksheet. The Excel cell values are calculated using formulas. When I run this code:

```
Set firstExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
firstExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Myroute\excelName.xls"
Set oSht = firstExcel.Worksheets("Input Data")
str="hello"
Set aCell = oSht.Range("A1:E15").Find(str, , xlValues)
MsgBox aCell.row
```

I have an error that says:

> Error: Subscript out of range
>   Code: 800A0009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get the error message on the `.Find` line is that vbscript does not recognize Excels constants, so you need to replace `xlValues` with the number `-4163`. (All Excel constant values can be found in the VBA Object Browser).

Also, the line you wrote `Set oSht = firstExcel.Worksheets("Input Data")` does not make sense to VB because `firstExcel` is the Excel Application itself and there is no *Worksheet* object associated with the Excel Application itself, but there is within the *Workbook* object.

```
Set firstExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set wkb = firstExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Myroute\excelName.xls")
Set oSht = wkb.Worksheets("Input Data")
str="hello"
Set aCell = oSht.Range("A1:E15").Find(str,,-4163)
If Not aCell is Nothing Then MsgBox aCell.row 'because if it does not find the string, it will not return a range object
```

Furthermore you could declare a constant at the top of your code and use that constant in the `.Find` statement.

```
const xlValues = -4163
.Find(str,,xlValues)
```

Comment: When I change my code to yours I get a new error:  Expected end of statement, in line:  Set wkb = firstExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Myroute\excelName.xls"

Comment: sorry, forgot parens in statement. see my edit and try again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried that but I still have that strange error using Find method. Thanks anyway.

Comment: did you copy the code into your file the **exact** way I have it written? Also, what is the *strange* error you are getting now?

Comment: Yes, I have copied it _exactly_ like you have written it. The error is still the same one: **Subscript out of range** (while using Find method at line number 5 - in the code bunch I've added on my question)

Comment: Ugh! Sorry, I figured it out. I am surprised I didn't see it sooner! Please see my edited answer and keep in mind going forward ...